# Function Reference/shortcode exists in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

how can i understand a short code is exist in my wordpress post?

[tbps id="1"]  is the short code . Where id may vary . ie 2,3 ...

i paste this code in wordpdpress post namely mypost ,it is working  .So how can i get the  shortcode which exists in wordpress page (in mypost).  i don't know how to use this code

```
<?php
    if ( shortcode_exists( 'yourCondition ' ) ) {
      //Here i don't know how to use   'yourCondition' .Because condition  
      //is    varying .It may be [tbps id="1"] ,[tbps id="2"] ,[tbps id="3"] etc
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ( shortcode_exists( 'yourCondition ' ) ) {
    // The [gallery] short code exists.
}

?>
```

you can try

Comment: but here my condition is always varying .ie it may be  [tbps id="1"],[tbps id="2"],[tbps id="3"]

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress 3.6 and above you can do this... Say your shortcode like this... [fts youtube username=GoProCamera vid_count=5]

```
// Detect if the shortcode exists in a post page or widget
global $post;
if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content,   'fts youtube') ) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'fts_youtube_css', plugins_url(  'youtube/css/styles.css',  dirname(__FILE__) ) );
        }
```

This works even if you use multiple shortcodes on a page, post or widget, and of course will not duplicate your styles or js because you are enqueueing them. Tested and confirmed. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode